How to fix TransactionManagementError in Django
I have Django project ,with mySQL as a database, which I work with my friend. My friend have work on certain feature in other branch. After he pass all the test I pull his code to my local repo and test it locally and I found this error while running test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/activities/tests/test_join.py", line 26, in test_join_unjoinable
    activity = create_activity("UnJoinable", 1, 10, 10)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/activities/tests/shortcuts.py", line 8, in create_activity
    activity = models.Activity.objects.create()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 891, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 997, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1160, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1201, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1847, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1836, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 92, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in _execute
    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()
  File "/Users/Ohm/Desktop/Ohm_project/ISP/ISP_project/ku-tangtee/env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 521, in validate_no_broken_transaction
    raise TransactionManagementError(
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.

I try to test it's manually with Django shell but everything run smoothly.
I've try to create a fresh new database for it and set ATOMIC_REQUESTS in settings to False but result are still the same. I'm not sure that do I need to configure something in MySQL or Django. Also all test are past in my friend machine and also in Github CI.
